# How to plot multiple columns with ggplot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I do have a data frame with different categorical and numerical columns with the following schema:

```
Country | Year | Conflict | Epidemics | Famine | Natural Disaster | Other
```

How to plot such a graph without redoing the data.frame?

[alt text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlsfX.png)

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score -2):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols = Conf.and.Terr:Other, names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = val, fill = var))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", width = 0.5, stat = "identity")
```